# Android In-call Audio

Tags: android

I am newbie to android, I am developing application in that after answering the incoming call, caller should hear prerecorded audio clip from receivers phone. Anyone knows how to achieve this.

Is this possible in android ?

I have tried all options

thanks in advance !!!

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to create some kind of voicemail app?
That would be hard... Since most phones aren't capable of recording calls.

Anyway - to your question: Put the phone on speaker mode and play a recording using MediaPlayer. That's the only way I know of that will work on ALL phones...

Comment: hey thanks,but is it possible without putting phone on speaker mode ? can it be possible in android to create voicemail app.

Comment: Been there, tried that... :) Only on a very small number of phone models / mods.